# View of Graph goes out of bounds when using SwiftCharts Framework

Tags: ios, swift, swiftcharts

So I am using the SwiftCharts Framework and trying to create a BarChart but the Chart goes out of view.

I create a UIView called view2, and then implement that following code.

```
func createChart(){
let chartConfig = BarsChartConfig(
    valsAxisConfig: ChartAxisConfig(from: 0, to: 8, by: 2)
)

let frame = view2.frame


let chart = BarsChart(
    frame: frame,
    chartConfig: chartConfig,
    xTitle: "X axis",
    yTitle: "Y axis",
    bars: [
        ("A", 2),
        ("B", 4.5),
        ("C", 3),
        ("D", 5.4),
        ("E", 6.8),
        ("F", 0.5)
    ],
    color: UIColor.red,
    barWidth: 20
)

self.chart = chart
view2.addSubview(chart.view)
self.view.addSubview(view2)
}
```

and get an output graph that looks like this. [image]

The graph should go on the first tray view, however it goes below for some reason. Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting frame get bounds of `view2` as frame of chart

Instead of this line

```
let frame = view2.frame
```

use below line

```
let frame = view2.bounds
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, that worked but there's still the problem of the upper number not being visible. Im talking about the "8" in this case, it's not fully visible. Any way to fix that?

Comment: If this answer solve your problem  upvote and accept the answer. Solution for your question in comment is to increase `view2` height

Comment: Increasing the height of view2, didn't fix it :(. It's still out of bounds. Do you know any specific properties of the SwiftCharts Framework to make it fit properly.